# How to get just English tweets using apache spark streaming and Java API from all?

Tags: java, apache-spark, twitter

Hello i am newbie in Spark)I would like to make some Spark project which will be collect and process tweets from this social network with help spark-streaming module(For my little university research). But i have got a little problem i don't now how to get tweets only in English.Can anyone help me with this?I tried to do filter operation with already received data but i have java.lang.NullPointerException at this line: "if (status.getPlace().getCountryCode().equals("(us)"))". But it's also bad solution.Is it possible to filter data before receiving? Please help i really don't now ho this.I'll be happy to get your hints.

```
package TwitterAnalysis;

import org.apache.spark.*;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.*;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.*;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.*;
import twitter4j.GeoLocation;
import twitter4j.Status;



public class Twitter {

    private static void setTwitterOAuth() {
        System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", TwitterOAuthKey.consumerKey);
        System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret", TwitterOAuthKey.consumerSecret);
        System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken", TwitterOAuthKey.accessToken);
        System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret", TwitterOAuthKey.accessTokenSecret);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {


        setTwitterOAuth();


        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("SparkTwitter");
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, new Duration(1000));


        JavaReceiverInputDStream<Status> twitterStream = TwitterUtils.createStream(jssc);

        //filtering already received tweets
        JavaDStream<Status> englishTweets=twitterStream.filter(
                new Function <Status, Boolean>(){
                    public Boolean call (Status status){
                        if (status.getPlace().getCountryCode().equals("(us)")){
                            return true;
                        }else
                        {return false;}
                    }
                }
        );


         //Without filter: Output text of all tweets
        JavaDStream<String> statuses = englishTweets.map(
                new Function<Status, String>() {
                    public String call(Status status) { return status.getText(); }
                }
        );




        statuses.print();
        jssc.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do something like that: lang:en keyword or lang:es for Spanish, lang:de for German and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer i just created new JavaDStream and used  getLang() for him. Solutions looks like this:

```
JavaDStream<Status> enTweetdDStream=twitterStream.filter((status) -> "en".equalsIgnoreCase(status.getLang()));
```